# How can I fix sfdx error: "The \"path\" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined" when I right click to deploy source to org?

Tags: salesforcedx

I've been at this for hours. I have gone through other solutions but they don't work for me. I even tried sfdx force:source:deploy -p [path]. But I receive the error message : **Error (1): Connection has no instanceUrl.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I get this error too.  It seems like there is some cache issue that I am creating by renaming a LWC outside VS Code.

Workaround:

1. Rename LWC (cause the issue)
2. Open VS Code
3. Get the error on deploy
4. Close VS Code
5. Open VS Code, no error on deploy.

It's annoying but it works consistently.

(I'm causing the issue by renaming LWC outside VS Code.  I'm refactoring several LWC names.  The SFDX: Rename Component fails on the SF end.

`11:36:36.993 Starting SFDX: Rename Component`

`EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'path\old name' -> 'path\new name'`

Also, there are names that need to be fixed inside a couple of the LWC files.  So I rename and edit the components as needed outside VS Code.  This causes the above error.  My workaround is annoying, but it works.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your authentication has expired or is otherwise corrupted. Try using *SFDX: Authorize an Org* from the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). If that fails, check your user's home directory for a folder/directory called `.sfdx` (e.g. `cd %USERPROFILE%/.sfdx` or `cd ~/.sfdx`), locate the username for the org there (e.g. `myuser@domain.com.json`) and delete the file, then try logging in again.